# Does PayPal Parallel Payments only work when paying multiple merchants?

Tags: paypal

I'm struggling to understand PayPals documentation, but is Parallel Payments intended to pay multiple *merchants* from a single buyer?

A previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203533/difference-between-paypal-parallel-payments-and-chained-payments) asks for the difference between Parallel and Chained payments, but no mention of this fact is in the answer.

What I need to do is pay money into multiple PayPal accounts which may not be merchant accounts. In this case is Chained Payments my only option?

Any advice here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. PayPal Adaptive Parallel Payments sends money from one buyer to multiple merchants.
PayPal Adaptive Chained Payments sends monety from one buyer, to 1 merchant (who can take his cut and will be the merchant of record) and the remainder is automatically forwarded to the second recipient.

Also take a look at [Introducing Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)

**Parallel payments**
[image: Adaptive Parallel Payments]

**Chained payments**
[image: Adaptive Chained Payments]

In addition to a slightly different flow, chained payments also allows you to designate another recipient as the one to pay the fees.
For example, if receiver 1 is going to be merchant of record, but you want receiver 2 to pay all the fees, you could set that up with Adaptive Payments as well.

Comment: This is what I thought, but I wanted somebody with more experience to verify it. Every time I have to touch PayPal it just drives me nuts.

Comment: It's gotten a whole lot better with Adaptive Payments really. It's not something you pick up on a lazy Sunday afternoon, but if you take the time to read the resources on https://www.x.com/ it's fairly easy to get up and running with in my opinion. Anyway, glad it helped! :-)

Comment: Yeah, I got it all working in the end, just wanted to make sure my understanding of how it works was correct. I'm hating PayPal a bit less, but I still find it pretty messy. Thanks again.

Comment: Does parallel payments/chained payments work with payments pro? ie. does it work with this https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/website-payments-pro

Comment: No, it doesn't. They're two different products altogether.